# Query Count assistance

Tags: sql

I have a query that isn't quite complete for my needs:

```
select COUNT(distinct OrderID)
from Images
where OrderID like 'btm%'
group by OrderID
```

Table looks like

Order ID

```
btm1
btm1
btm1
btm2
btm2
btm3
```

I want to return:

```
btm1 | 3
btm2 | 2
btm3 | 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select orderid, count(*) from Images group by orderid
```

Answer (score 2):

Addition to what @Zdravko Danev has, you could add the like clause if its really needed in your query:

```
select orderid,COUNT(orderid)
from t1
where orderid like 'btm%'
group by orderid
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/887776/2)